# Android Viewpager Display specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to know if it is possible to display a specific `fragment` in a `view pager`. What I have at the moment is a G`ridview` and the `onClick` sends a id via Intent to a `viewPager`. The `View pager` has six items. So how would I go about displaying the third `Fragment`? (with an id of 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ViewPager [setCurrentItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29) method. You probably want the param smoothScroll to be false, so it seems like it's always been at that position:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
```